# Why is time represented on the vertical axis in space-time diagrams?

Tags: relativity-theory

One thing that bugs me when learning and explaining special relativity concepts is that the time axis on space-time charts always on the vertical axis. While almost everywhere else time is going on the horizontal axis.

Moreover space-time coordinates often written in the order of $(t, x, y, z)$. And in case of 1 dimensions $(t, x)$. Now when we speak of the event $(A, B)$, $A$ goes on the vertical axis $B$ on the horizontal and not vice versa as it usually goes on the coordinate charts.

So I always need to twist my mind a bit when working with it.

When did we started putting time on the vertical axis and what's the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons I can think of:

Minkowski's paper *Space & Time* (in Wikipedia).

Geometry: a circle is x^2+y^2=R, a family of ever widening circles is x^2+y^2=R.t;
stacking the circles gives a cone which is the usual x^2+y^2=t^2.